# Background image resizing

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to design a website with a background image that should stretch in height and width
accordingly when the browser window is resizing. It is complicated to explain what exact behaviour I would like to achieve, for this reason here is the website that does it perfectly:

http://de.wix.com/website-template/view/html/709?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fde.wix.com%26number-of-page%3D1%26position-in-page%3D4

I used background-size set to everything possible as well as background-width set to 100%, but
I could not achieve such a behaviour.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311839/proper-css-positioning-help-needed/24312094#24312094

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the below CSS? This fills the page background with the image.

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, thanks. What is with the grey side bar on the left, would it work accordingly?

Comment: Why is this answer being upvoted when it is newer and includes unnecessary code (vendor prefixes)? I am perplexed.

Comment: @Tom the grey sidebar (from your example) is independent of the background image, they will have no effect on each other

Comment: im thinking only the `-webkit-` is still needed today (for older android)... the others are for *really* old versions http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: @Grapho: I know, I asked it wrongly, it is just that I was wondering if I need to specify something specific in css or float: left with margin would be enough to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: @Tom sure, you could do it that way, but it would be best to ask that as a different question.  In this case, it looks like your example has a layout inside container with just a set width and auto margins on the left/right

Comment: @Grapho: I don't think left and right margins are set to auto, because it would center the div.. but this div is not centered

Comment: @Tom the *container* is centered. the grey sidebar and the main content area are *inside* of that.

Comment: @Grapho: I see it now, the div contains the navigation bar and the left side bar and it is centered. Thanks, I did not see that the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Without any HTML or CSS of your own, it's impossible for us to truly help you, but generally this behavior can be achieved with the following property: [background-size: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images#cover)

```
background-image: url('URLGOESHERE');
    height: ???;
    background-size: cover;
```

As long as you specify an explicit height (pixels) and do **not** specify a width, this property should cause the background-image to resize while maintaining aspect ratio.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/MXH9V/) Example.